# Description of Concrete Classification Numbers (e.g. C15, C25 etc.)

Tags: concrete, cement

I was reading my plumbing code and came across mysterious concrete classification numbers like **C15** and **C25**.

I tried googling it and only came across a couple of sources describing these numbers (like [here](http://www.fleximix.co.uk/concrete-mixes/) and [here](http://www.bulgarianbuildingservices.com/how-tos/how-to-mix-concrete/) for example), but these sources do not appear authoritative.

Where can I find an authoritative description (preferably online) of these concrete classification numbers?

Comment: Try the American Society for Testing and Measures (ATSM.org).